# How can I know the extremum of a polynomial regression curve generated by geom_smooth in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, non-linear-regression

I began to have this question while reading this book "*R for Data Science*" by Hadley Wickham. In the chapter of "Data Transformation", the author used this example:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
by_dest <- group_by(flights, dest)
delay <- summarise(by_dest,
  count = n(),
  dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE),
  delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)
)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
delay <- filter(delay, count > 20, dest != "HNL")

# It looks like delays increase with distance up to ~750 miles 
# and then decrease. Maybe as flights get longer there's more 
# ability to make up delays in the air?
ggplot(data = delay, mapping = aes(x = dist, y = delay)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = count), alpha = 1/3) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

The output plot looks like as follows:
[relationship between delay and flight distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjENb.png)

**So I wonder if we can know the extremum of the curve and the corresponding x value using R?**

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/add-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph), I've figured using stat_poly_eq() from ggpmisc to calculate the polynomial regression equation:

```
library(ggpmisc)    
formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)
p <- ggplot(data = delay, mapping = aes(x = dist, y = delay)) 
p <- p + geom_point(aes(size = count), alpha = 1/3) 
p <- p+ geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula, se = FALSE)
(p1 <- p+ stat_poly_eq(formula = formula, aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE))
```

[Polynomial Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkfFq.png)

And use that equation to find out the extremum of the curve, which I think it's very not clever. So I wonder how can I figure out the extremum and the corresponding x value of my regression curve (not the max and min value of raw data but the max and the min value of the regression curve).

Comment: don't have time to answer right now, but you can get there by running `ggplot_build()` on your `ggplot` object (assuming you have saved it to a variable), extracting the `$data` component, figuring out which layer corresponds to the data generated by `geom_smooth()`, and then looking for the max value of the `y` variable in that data frame. (This will only be the maximum y value in the set of predicted points from the smooth, not the absolute maximum ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your first code snippet, your `ggplot` call outputs this message:

```
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html) for `geom_smooth` and `stat_smooth`:

> stats::loess() is used for less than 1,000 observations; otherwise mgcv::gam() is used with formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs") with method = "REML".

So you could just call `stats::loess` on your data to fit the model implied by the `geom_smooth` curve, and then use the `predict` method to get values outside of your actual range.